# Ubuntu 21.10 upgrade went without a glitch... except gnome

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 21.10

As usual the 21.10 upgrade caused the loss of all gnome-shell extensions, which in plain English means that **ALL** the customization of my desktop will have to be done all over again starting from scratch. Now I am stuck with a tweaks tool that does not have anything in the gnome-shell box and no extensions tab in the menu. Hovering with the mouse over the gnome-shell triangle (yes the one with the exclamation mark) informs me that the 'shell user-theme extension' is not enabled. Why ***I*** should have to enable the blessed thing together with a dozen extensions that worked fine as of yesterday... (and **how** I am supposed to do it)... is anybody's guess.

The upgrade took about 30 minutes and went without a glitch and now I have already wasted a couple of hours trying to figure out how to fix this broken desktop.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Found this article that explains it all and my gnome desktop is pretty much back to where it was yesterday: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/gnome-tweaks-40-no-longer-manage-extensions/. This actually reminded me of something I thought: what['s the point of this tweaks tool when we have something called settings that should have all the tweaks Joe User is ever going to need... So I says to meself.... why not another tweaks-tweaks tool that lets you tweak the tweaks... Well now we have it: it's called 'extensions'!

Comment: No need to file a bug... Perhaps the ubuntu team who appear to have done a fantastic job otherwise should have put some kind of full screen warning on the do-release-upgrade screen pointing users of the gnome-based flavour of ubuntu that they should/must take a peek at the article I linked in my above comment.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution in the ***ubuntu handbook***: if you run into this same issue please read the entry titled: **Gnome Tweaks 40 No Longer Manage Extensions, Use This Tool Instead**. Tells you everything you need to do...

In a nutshell: one needs to fire up something called 'extensions': just open the application search box at the top of the screen by pressing `<Super>` and type `e x t . . .` and you should see and icon that looks like a green puzzle piece and take it from there.